# How to print correct path to file in .tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

```
<img src="<?php print($base_path . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik')); ?>images/some-image.png">
```

The above code works only if you're in the homepage. If you go to any inner page, it looks for image inside the current URL, not just base URL.

So, it prints the image if you're under `www.address.com` but if you're under `www.address.com/page`, it doesn't print the image, because now it's looking for it inside e.g. `www.address.com/page/sites/all/themes/bartik/images/some-image.png` the problem is, it includes the `/page/` part.

In source, the image URL doesn't include the full path (which is the problem I believe?), only the `sites/all/themes/bartik/images/some-image.png` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears `$base_path` is empty, which would suggest your code isn't in page.tpl.php (where that var is commonly available, having been added in [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x)).

To make it available to your current template, implement a preprocess hook like the following, which is for a region.tpl.php template file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {  
  $vars['base_path'] = base_path();
}
```